# Latex / Tikz: draw a vertical line to a straight line

Tags: math, latex, draw, pdflatex, tikz

Maybe you can help me, I try to draw a line from a Point/Coordinate to a straight line. I use Tikz to draw.

```
      \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-5,-5){};
      \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (5,-5) {};
      \coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (5,1) {};
      \coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (-5,1) {};

      \draw [thick] (A) -- node[midway] {$\parallel$} (B) -- node[sloped]{$\parallel$} (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

      \coordinate (S1) at ($(D)!0.66!(C)$);
      \coordinate (S2) at ($(A)!0.11!(B)$);
      \draw [very thick] (S1) -- node[above]{x} (S2);
      \draw [red!100, thick] (S1) -- node[above]{T} (A -| B );
      \end{tikzpicture}
```

[This where the red line should go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej1Aa.png)

the red line should go from coordinate (S1) to the straight line (A -- B) vertically.
I tried it to draw it like this:

```
     \draw [red!100, thick] (S1) -- node[above]{T} (A -| B );
```

But then he draw a line to coordinate A

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a new coordinate but you can use the projection identifiers from `calc` library.

In the last line you just need

```
\draw [red!100, thick] (S1) -- node[left]{T} ($(A)!(S1)!(B)$);
```

This mean along A--B take the point which S1 is projected onto A--B.

Comment: In this case you can just use the tee operation as the OP tried to do, but with the correct coordinates.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Only in this case when A -- B is horizontal.

Comment: Indeed the tee is only for horizontal/vertical case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by defining a new coordinate (say `S3`) for the point on AB:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-5,-5){};
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (5,-5) {};
\coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (5,1) {};
\coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (-5,1) {};

\draw [thick] (A) -- node[midway] {$\parallel$} (B) -- node[sloped]{$\parallel$} (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

\coordinate (S1) at ($(D)!0.66!(C)$);
\coordinate (S2) at ($(A)!0.11!(B)$);
\coordinate (S3) at ($(A)!0.66!(B)$);
\draw [very thick] (S1) -- node[above]{x} (S2);
\draw [red!100, thick] (S1) -- node[left]{T} (S3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is nearly correct, but the tee operators `|-` and `-|` take the x coordinate from one side and the y coordinate from other.  When you write
`A -| B` you get the y coordinate of A and the x coordinate of B, but in your code A and B have the same x coordinate so this gives you the point A again.  Instead you want `A -| S1`, or equivalently `S1 |- A`.

```
 \draw [red!100, thick] (S1) --   node[left]{T} (S1 |- A);
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-5,-5){};
      \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (5,-5) {};
      \coordinate [label=right:$C$] (C) at (5,1) {};
      \coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (-5,1) {};

      \draw [thick] (A) -- node[midway] {$\parallel$} (B) -- node[sloped]{$\parallel$} (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

      \coordinate (S1) at ($(D)!0.66!(C)$);
      \coordinate (S2) at ($(A)!0.11!(B)$);
      \draw [very thick] (S1) -- node[above]{x} (S2);
      \draw [red!100, thick] (S1) --   node[left]{T} (S1 |- A);
      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```